# Flagged question as Off topic, suggestions on where it should be

Tags: feature-request, flags, off-topic

Hi, I spend most of my time on StackOverflow looking at questions tagged with the [Android] tag. It is fairly common that people ask questions on there that should really be on the android.stackexchange instead. When I flag the questions for mod attention and choose off-topic as the reason it gives me a list of other .stackexchange sites where it should possibly be. But Android.stackexchange is not among them. I haven't noticed any way for me to specify one that is not on the list. But is there a way to do so? That way when I flag it as off-topic I can report that it should be on android.stackexchange instead of just marking it as offtopic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you flag for moderator attention we can move it to any site in the Stack Exchange network.  Just let us know where you think it should go.

Comment: Thats my question though. There are a list of options presented when I flag something for where I think it should go. But Android.stackexchange is not among them. How can I specify one that is not on the list? Or instead of choosing off-topic should I just use 'Other' and type out that it belongs on Android.stackexchange?

Comment: @Tim: Instead of the close link, click the flag link and select "other" and just tell us which site.  Only moderators get the full list of sites.